# Split function in c#

Tags: c#, split-function

I have a program which accepts a url(example:care.org), gets the page source of the url and does some calculation.

```
  string text = <the page source of care.org>
  string separator = "car";
  var cnt = text.ToLower().Split(separator,StringSplitOptions.None);
```

My aim is to count the number of occurence of the "car" in the page source,
My code considers care as 'car'|'e' it splits it this way.. But i want it to consider whole seperator as one and do the splittin

Please help me with this

Comment: This looks like a job for [regular expressions](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/217-how-to-match-whole-words-with-a-regular-expression/).

Comment: I want to use the split function nothing else

Comment: Do you also use a screwdriver to hammer in a nail? Use the most appropriate tool for the task. Regexes were designed exactly for these kind of tasks.

Comment: in .Split(), separator should be a char type otherwise use regex.match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use reular expressions instead of split() method:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\bcar\b"); // you should modify it if `car's` needed

Match match = regex.Match(text);
int cnt = 0;

while (match.Success)
{
   cnt++;
   match = match.NextMatch();
}

// here you get count of `car` in `cnt`
```

Comment: check: `var cnt = text.ToLower().Split(separator, Int32.MaxValue, StringSplitOptions.None).Count;`

Comment: I think you need to consider word boundaries. As I understand OP, he want's "care" to *not* match.

Comment: as of now everything was working fine. But now by split characters have increased. now i have to split using special characters as well this is my characters /[\s,.'/:;&nbsp;<>[](){}@!#-_+?]+/ i am confused where i should use the backslash (escape character) please help

Answer (score 1):

This is how can achieve what you want by using `RegularExpressions`:

```
string text = "the page source of care.org";
string separator = @"\bcar\b";
MatchCollection resultsarray = Regex.Matches(text, separator);
```

Now `resultsarray` contains your matches. You can count it using

```
resultsarray.Count
```

Comment: Basically this. But if I understand correctly, OP want's to match "car" and *not* "care", so "Take care of your car. And take care of your cat." should only have one match.

Answer (score 0):

Split returns a string array, you could just count the results.

```
var cnt = text.ToLower().Split(separator,StringSplitOptions.None).count;
```

Comment: will it consider care as a whole as in my example. As i dont want the count a care, i want the count of car. It shows me the count of care this way

Comment: what about using regex.split? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8yttk7sy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to split, since you are not going to do anything with the substring. You only want a count, so look in to using `RegEx.Matches(text, "car[^a-zA-Z0-9]")` or similar to define the patterns you are interested in. Good luck!